# Better exception call stack in Firebase Crashlytics for React Native app

Tags: firebase, react-native, crashlytics

I' receiving some crash reports in my Firebase Crashlytics dashboard. However, the report only shows native code call stacks, and JS stack is minimized and un-readable. For example:

```
Fatal Exception: com.facebook.react.common.JavascriptException: undefined is not a function (evaluating 'r[n]()'), stack:
<unknown>@284:210
value@36:1363
value@23:3582
<unknown>@23:1067
value@23:3009
value@23:1039

       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.showOrThrowError(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:54)
       at com.facebook.react.modules.core.ExceptionsManagerModule.reportFatalException(ExceptionsManagerModule.java:38)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaMethodWrapper.invoke(JavaMethodWrapper.java:372)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.JavaModuleWrapper.invoke(JavaModuleWrapper.java:160)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.NativeRunnable.run(NativeRunnable.java)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadHandler.dispatchMessage(MessageQueueThreadHandler.java:29)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
       at com.facebook.react.bridge.queue.MessageQueueThreadImpl$3.run(MessageQueueThreadImpl.java:192)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:764)
```

The only thing I can get from the above report is that the JS code is trying to invoke an undefined object, but it's hard to locate where exactly the issue is at.

Is it possible to submit a symbol file or mapping file of some kind, so that this report can be more useful to help me see which function is having the problem?

Thank you.

Comment: Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/53015830/5508175